# Batch script to provide only the server name

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have the list of several server name that has the combination of server name + Environment

Example: VHS001 DEV, VHS002 UAT, VHS003 PROD. I need to filter the environment name and only need the server name.

Here is the code I tried, but i can get only the first server name, the rest of the servers are ignored. Please help to fix the code:

```
set serverlist=%serverlist%
for /f "tokens=1 delims= " %%a in ("%serverlist%") do ( 
    set server=%%a
    echo !server!
```

%serverlist% = VHS001 DEV, VHS002 UAT, VHS003 PROD

The previous code returns the output in the form of %serverlist%.

Now I am passing this as input to retrieve the server name alone.

Comment: You need to show us exactly what the content of `%serverlist%` is, and explain how and where it was defined. Is your first line supposed to be ```set serverlist=VHS001 DEV, VHS002 UAT, VHS003 PROD```? If so, then you don't want to use the space character to delimit your tokens, and select only the first, otherwise `!server!` will always return as just `VHS001`, _if delayed variable expansion is enabled_.

Comment: Sorry, that's not good enough. We need a [mcve]. That means we should be able to run your code in the same way as you, in a similar/same environment, and get the exact same results. Never is there a need to have a line reading as ```set serverlist=%serverlist%``` in a batch file, and neither will there ever be the line ```%serverlist% = VHS001 DEV, VHS002 UAT, VHS003 PROD```. We need to see the exact code, which is used to define the variable named `serverlist`. We should also see how and when you dealt with variable expansion. Please try harder if you want us to help you with your script!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to split your list two times (because it's actually a list of lists)

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "serverlist=VHS001 DEV, VHS002 UAT, VHS003 PROD"
echo DEBUG: "%serverlist:,=","%"
for %%a in ("%serverlist:,=","%") do (
  for /f "tokens=1,2" %%b in ("%%~a") do echo %%b is %%c.
)
```

Output:

```
DEBUG: "VHS001 DEV"," VHS002 UAT"," VHS003 PROD"
VHS001 is DEV.
VHS002 is UAT.
VHS003 is PROD.
```

`%%a` is the list elements ("sublists"), `%%b` is your servernames, `%%c` is your Environments (you can ignore it - just in case you need it later)

The outer `for` splits the list into `"server environment"` elements (including the quotes - they are critical because of the space), which is the delimiter to further split the elements with the inner `for /f` loop.

In the debug line you can see the three "element lists". The spaces don't matter, they are removed by the inner `for /f` loop.